# Pause the execution until Batch File finishes

Tags: c#, batch-file

I'm running a batch file using Process. The problem is I want the batch file to finish its execution and then the next set of lines should be executed. 
Here's the code snippet.

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + sFileName+".bat";
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
proc.Start();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
// Method which will be executed after the batch file
Method1();
```

Method1() should execute only when the batch file has completed its execution.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply call

```
proc.WaitForExit();
Method1();
```

> Instructs the Process component to wait the specified number of milliseconds for the associated process to exit.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx

Note there is no need for your

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this method:

```
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Here are the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx)